# How to access the response i get from POSTing with $.ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, post, custom-headers

I'm not a professional programmer and trying to pick this up from the web, so sorry in advance if my question seems stupid, but i've been spending the last 2 days researching this to no avail.

### Here's my code:

```
function view(data)
{
    alert (data);
}

function test()
{
    var url = 'someurl';

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: url,
        async: false,
        contentType: "application/json",
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        data: "Basic=YWRtaW46cHNhZG0xbg==",
        headers: {
            "Basic": 'YWRtaW46cHNhZG0xbg=='
        },
        success: view(data)
    })
}
```

But whenever i run it, i get an error saying: "data is not defined".
How do i access the actual response the request got?
I believe that if you guys could give me a code that alerts the response (but uses my code) i can take it from there.

Thanks!!!

---

So Guys, first of all huge thanks for the fast and detailed response!

i tried both methods, and i didn't get an error for "undefined data", i guess what i don't understand is, what function am i calling?? and how come when i just want to put the "data" inside of a variable i need a function to proxy?

that being said, i've encounterd a new issue - for some reason FF/Chrome are ignoring the properties i've set and are sending it without the headers and as a "GET which is resulting in an error:

```
Request .com:xxxx?callback=jQuery191023387945420108736_1384464320088&        Basic=YWRtaW46cHNhZG0xbg==&_=1384464320089
Request Method:GET
Status Code:401 Unauthorized
Request Headersview source
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Cache-Control:no-cache
Connection:keep-alive
Cookie:JSESSIONID=EC56CA6ADB540E1B6785B318DD0886CD
Host:IP:8083
Pragma:no-cache
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)     Chrome/30.0.1599.101 Safari/537.36
Query String Parametersview sourceview encoded
callback:jQuery191023387945420108736_1384464320088
Basic:YWRtaW46cHNhZG0xbg
_:1384464320089
Response Headersview source
Content-Length:77
Date:Wed, 13 Nov 2013 11:15:40 GMT
Secsph-Request-Id:1164775931060804669
Server:NA"
```

the main request is also accompanied by a secondary one which i'm not sure what invokes it or if it's related to the issue:

```
Request :nikkomsgchannel        /e?00160023002b00550046004b00660050005e005800280055005c007a002200590050004d004a005600520004002000530055003600210010005d005900540056000b006a003300500054002c0030005400470056001f0047004f00490023000f005b003000300042005c0056001f00550059004b002b000f0057002c002f005d005c00560050005f005a
Request Headersview source
Cache-Control:no-cache
Pragma:no-cache
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)     Chrome/30.0.1599.101 Safari/537.36
Query String Parametersview sourcevie encoded
00160023002b00550046004b00660050005e005800280055005c007a002200590050004d004a005600520004002000530055003600210010005d0
```

any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
function test() {
    var url = 'someurl';

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: url,
        async: false,
        contentType: "application/json",
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        data: "Basic=YWRtaW46cHNhZG0xbg==",
        headers: {
            Basic: 'YWRtaW46cHNhZG0xbg=='
        },
        success: function (data) {
            alert(JSON.stringify(data));
        }
    });
}
```

This seems to be what you're trying to do (alert the JSON string)

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
function test() {
            var url = 'someurl';
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: url,
                async: false,
                contentType: "application/json",
                dataType: 'jsonp',
                data: "Basic=YWRtaW46cHNhZG0xbg==",
                headers: {
                    "Basic": 'YWRtaW46cHNhZG0xbg=='
                },
                success: function(data) {
                     console.log(data);
                     // /\ this will show on console the returned data.
                     //the variable 'data' actually contains the returned data.
                     // here you can do whatever you want with the returned data
                     //if you want to alert the response:
                     alert(data);
                }
           });
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

When you do `success: view(data)` that executes `view(data)` immediately (attempting to pass `data` which doesn't currently exist to the `view` function), and attempts to set the returned value from that function as the `success` callback.

What you instead need to do is simply pass a function reference as the callback, so:

```
success: view
```

The `view` function will then be called when the AJAX request returns a successful response, and pass the response as the argument to the `data` parameter.

Comment: Got it!!thanks a lot everyone for your help! i've updated the original question, any thought on why the parameters are being ignored?